# Mango Automation time-related functions

Tags: javascript, html, dashboard

I'm just getting started with Mango Automation. Trying to build a control page for this Modbus serial thing. I'm on Mango Automation V5.0.3, using Win10 and Chrome Version 120.0.6099.217.

Most of it makes sense, but I'm stuck on dealing with time data. I can't figure out how to set up a page with a simple on/off switch (Start/Stop), and three fields for showing start time, stop time, and uptime, even during those Start/Stop switches. And, oh, I also want to show the Duration, both in time format and as a plain old integer counting seconds.

What virtual data points do I need, and how should I format them? Anyone out there who can lend a hand to this newbie coder?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem.
The page is working, all the required results have been obtained. However, I can't remove the extra 1 in the number of days when displaying Duration. How can this be done?
And I would very much like to understand how correct and optimal the methods I applied.
To start a page, paste next text into a blank new page in the page editor in mango

```
<div class="ma-designer-root" id="11c26dc1-8e3d-475e-ba22-1b6d9c37eb0c" style="width: 1366px; height: 768px; position: relative; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 255);">
<ma-get-point-value point-xid="startTime" point="_startTime"></ma-get-point-value>
<ma-get-point-value point-xid="stopTime" point="_stopTime"></ma-get-point-value>
<ma-get-point-value point-xid="Start" point="_Start"></ma-get-point-value>
<ma-switch id="0022dde1-a203-4176-a0eb-9b120feb36a3" style="position: absolute; left: 220px; top: 60px; font-weight: bold; font-family: fantasy; text-align: center; width: 100px; height: 70px; background-color: rgb(153, 153, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" display-type="switch" point="Start" label="NAME" point-xid="Start" ng-click="_Start.value ? (_stopTime.setValue(_stopTime.time)) :  (_startTime.setValue(_startTime.time))">Start</ma-switch>
    <ma-now update-interval="1 SECONDS" output="time" browser-timezone="browserTz"></ma-now>
<div id="7ebdece1-8366-4df8-b660-62c0c19da235" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px; width: 170px; height: 30px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 13px; font-size: 20px; font-family: fantasy;">{{time|maMoment:'format':' DD.MM.YY HH:mm:ss  '}}</div>
<div id="b554c70c-e4ab-49f8-89be-0b1348180c96" style="position: absolute; left: 370px; top: 70px; width: 210px; height: 30px;">Start time:  {{_startTime.value|maMoment:'format':' DD.MM.YY HH:mm:ss '}}</div>
<div id="55e794bb-b763-4d59-b2c7-b03bfac43d87" style="position: absolute; left: 370px; top: 100px; width: 210px; height: 30px;" ng-show="_Start.value === false">Stop time :{{_stopTime.value|maMoment:'format':' DD.MM.YY HH:mm:ss '}}</div>
<div id="36cc40c9-66d1-4369-9b29-b18edf4cb066" style="position: absolute; left: 670px; top: 90px; width: 210px; height: 30px;" ng-show="_Start.value === false">{{(_stopTime.value-_startTime.value)/1000}}{{"sec = "}} {{((_stopTime.value-_startTime.value))|maMoment:'tz':'UTC'|maMoment:'format':'DDDD[day] HH:mm:ss '}}</div>
<ma-indicator id="af49567e-6576-49f5-9bdd-8d8808324cbc" style="position: absolute; width: 30px; height: 30px; left: 330px; top: 80px;" color-false="#ff0000" color-true="#00f500" toggle-on-click="true" point="_Start"></ma-indicator>
<div id="fe605657-ed93-4361-9755-7d4ff023ed1f" style="position: absolute; left: 670px; top: 90px; width: 140px; height: 30px;" ng-show="_Start.value">{{(_stopTime.time-_startTime.value)/1000}}sec</div>
<div id="fffc771a-27b3-463b-b464-fdaf9db2841d" style="position: absolute; left: 590px; top: 90px; width: 150px; height: 30px;">Duration:</div></div>
```

and import the file [export_Time_Demo.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xGzhIVidyaKcCMob8EeWOMxn1kGjxC3e/view?usp=drive_link) into Data integration->Configuration Import/Export.
Looking forward to your comments. Thank you.